# Drupal: Change of access level for multiple nodes

Tags: mysql, drupal

I want to change the *access level* of *multiple nodes* (e.g from public to authenticated user) without triggering the "updated" field. 
I thought about changing it on database level. I'm familiar with relational databases and could connect to the underlying database. But I can't find out how the access level of the nodes is handled there.

DB Scheme: https://www.drupal.org/files/er_db_schema_drupal_7.png

In which table is the access level defined? Does there exist any other possibility for my problem (e.g using a module)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is node_access table where you can find the access level of a node id(nid) to a group id (gid). Whenever a node is loaded, drupal will check its node access to current user from this table. So you can update this table directly.

Here is some more grant related information :- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7